# gksudo doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04 - did work before

Tags: 12.04, gksu

I am running this command in a script:

```
    $ gksudo wminput -q -r 00:22:D7:E2:A0:18
```

However it just outputs the manual page. It seems like gksudo is taking the parameters meant to be taken by wminput.

Could anyone shed any light on this?

Cheers-SM.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command instead:

```
gksudo 'wminput -q -r 00:22:D7:E2:A0:18'
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. The script just skipped that line and ran the remaining commands. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry - my fault. Was using double-quotes instead of single quotes! Cheers for your answer which I've marked as the answer.